# Cartesian coordinate system in Newton's work

Tags: mathematics, notation

In the english translation of Newton's work "Enumeratio linearum tertii ordinis" by C.R.M. Talbot, we can see [in a figure](https://books.google.gr/books?id=6I97byFB3v0C&hl=el&pg=PA86#v=onepage&q&f=false) the depiction of a Cartesian coordinate system pretty much as we know it today: two perpendicular axes labeled X, Y intersected at the origin O. Is it possible that this figure corresponds to some of the original Newton's drawings? I cannot find it in the [latin edition](https://archive.org/stream/isaacinewtonien00newtgoog#page/n211/mode/2up).

Comment: What's surprising about this? Coordinate systems were used since Descartes.

Comment: Not exactly in this form, I suppose. See e.g. Victor J. Katz's History of Mathematics, 3rd edition, p. 484  

"Both [Descartes and Fermat] used as their basic tool a single axis along which one of the unknowns was measured rather than the two axes used today, and neither insisted that the lines measuring the second unknown intersect the single axis at right angles"  
I'm interested in the evolution of the concept and I'm wondering if this figure belongs actually to the translator, not to Newton.

Comment: I wonder if someone can come up with one (or more?) tags to better describe this question...

Comment: @skol, perhaps you should ask about the development of the "cartesian" coordinate system of perpendicular axes instead.

Comment: Your link is to the translator's notes, not to the translation itself. Talbot has simply reformulated Newton's argument in modern mathematical language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way we represent Cartesian coordinates with orthogonal axis is not present into Descartes' [La Géométrie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_G%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_(Descartes)) nor into Newton's works.

An early occurrence of the "basic" definitions are in :

- [Colin McLaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colin_Maclaurin)'s [A Treatise on Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=QoAHAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1) (1748 - two years after his death); see page 297-on:

> §2. We are now to consider quantities as represented by *lines*. [ [page 301](https://books.google.it/books?id=QoAHAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA301) ] So that, if $AP$ represent $x$, and the prependicular $PM$ represent the corresponding values of $y$, then there will be as many points ($M$,) the extremities of these perpendiculars or *ordinates* [...].

The modern representation (as usual), is due to [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) into his [Introductio in analysin infinitorum](https://books.google.it/books?id=q9br6CFATEcC&pg=PA403), (1748), Tomus Secundus.

See page 3 for an "elucidation" of *function* and page 4:

> Sit igitur $x$ quantitas variabilís, quae per rectam indefinitam $RS$  repraesentetur, atque manifestum est omnes valores determinatos ipsius $x$, qui quidem sint reales, per portiones in recta $RS$ abscindendas repraesentari posse. [...] Vocantur аutem haec intervalla $АР$, ABSCISSAE. Atque ideo Abscissae exhibent variabilis $x$ valores determinatos.
>
> [page 7] Portiones autem Axis $АР$, quibus determinati ipsius $x$ valores indicantur, vocari solent $ABSCISSAE$.
>
> Et perpendiculares $PM$, ex terminis *Abscissarum* $M$ ad lineam curvam pertingentes, nomen $APPLICATARUM$ obtinuerunt.
>
> Vocantur autem hoc casu Applicatae *normales* seu *orthogonales*, quin cum Axe angulum rectum constituunt.

---

In general, we can see :

- Carl Boyer, [History of analytic geometry](https://books.google.it/books?id=2T4i5fXZbOYC&printsec=frontcover) (1956 - also Dover reprint).

Answer (score 1):

Philippe de la Hire *Nouveaux elements de sections coniques* published in 1679 seems a good candidate for inventing cartesian coordinates: he was strongly influenced by Descartes and draw conics by referring them to an origin *O*, a vertical axis called a stem ('tige')  with  knots 'noeuds' *N* and horizontal branches 'rameaux' *NL*. This is probably the source for the popular view that Descartes invented the left handed coordinate system.