# History of points with coordinates notation

Tags: mathematics, notation, geometry

In this MathEducator StackExchange article, "[Notation of points with coordinates](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/notation-of-points-with-coordinates)", it's posed the question about what is the best notation for geometrical points and their coordinates: $P(3, 4)$ or $P = (3, 4)$?

Peharps History of Mathematics could help with this discussion: what is the first known written register of such association point <-> coordinates? Did $P(3, 4)$ come first, for instance?

Descartes' "La Géométrie" has no such explicit association.

Somehow, this question is related to the posts "[When do we see for the first time the use of the Cartesian coordinates?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/when-do-we-see-for-the-first-time-the-use-of-the-cartesian-coordinates/2382#2382)" and "[Cartesian coordinate system in Newton's work](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/cartesian-coordinate-system-in-newtons-work)". But, in the references given, I've found no explicit association either.

Comment: What came first hardly has any bearing on what is better, even assuming that it is not a purely subjective preference. Early notations were often clumsy. In this case, one can use both expressions for different purposes, first as a point's name labeled by its coordinates, and second as identifying a point with its tuple of coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the notation $P(x,y)$ is "more correct".

See e.g. Felix Klein, [Elementary Mathematics from an Advanced Standpoint: Geometry (1908)](https://books.google.it/books?id=JazDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA10), page 10.

As you have already noted, the usual representation of the coordinate plane is quite late: I suppose that we cannot find it in any 19th Century treatise regarding Analytic Geometry.